# Is Tkinter worth learning?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I generally make my desktop interfaces with [Qt](http://www.pyside.org/), but some recent TK screenshots convince me Tk isn't just ugly motif any more.
Additionally [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) comes bundled with Python, which makes distribution easier.

So is it worth learning or should I stick with Qt?

[image: example tk interface]
<sub>(source: [kb-creative.net](http://www.kb-creative.net/screenshots/ipats-multifile.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to your question is a resounding **yes**.

Qt is good, I have nothing against it. But Tk is better and far easier to use and quite [well documented](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) - not just on the Python webspace, but there are also many third-party tutorials out there. [This](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/) particular one is where I learned it from and it has been quite infallible in serving me.

Comment: Tk uses the default system displays and this is quite apparent in most situations. Also, when you have multiple elements in a display (like a window for example), then Tk does the "administrative work" behind the scenes to make sure that all your elements are shown and fit within the window, which not too many other toolkits do for you

Comment: It has been multiple months since I wrote this answer. Now the times have changed and I should note that easygui makes things a lot easier. It also allows for access to Tkinter if you really want to hack at Tkinter. I would suggest using easygui over Tkinter because it's easier to use.

Comment: I would recommend learning Tkinter, personally. It's easier than other stuff I've tried (except that some stuff isn't built-in and you have to build it yourself; however, building it yourself is actually possible, which is part of what makes Tkinter so nice; you can build custom stuff pretty easily). The Python help function goes a long way with Tkinter. Tkinter does take time to learn well, but learn you can learn, and there are very helpful people, such as Bryan Oakley, for example, on Stackoverflow to help you.

Comment: "Tk uses the default system displays" Then why does it look so ugly and non-native?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at [this(wxPython)](http://www.wxpython.org/quotes.php).

> wxPython is the best and most mature cross-platform GUI toolkit, given a number of constraints. The only reason wxPython isn't the standard Python GUI toolkit is that Tkinter was there first.
>   -- Guido van Rossum

Comment: what does wx offer that qt doesn't? Anyway, my main motivation for tk is that it comes bundled with Python, which makes distribution easier for me.

Comment: @Richard Nice comparison on http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits

Comment: any specifics? The only possible advantage I read was using native widgets, but Qt's appearance is fine for me. 
Downsides are wx looks harder to distribute, less commercial support, no equivalent to Qt Creator, no styling. 
Anyway, my purpose here is not to find a Python GUI library but decide whether to stick with Qt or try Tkinter.

Comment: I can't agree with the "most mature" part of that equation. Tk is very, very mature, and arguably more robust than wxPython. I don't think I can recall the last time I saw a core dump in Tk. With wxPython it happens a lot during development.

Answer (score 4):

As a step up to other GUI toolkits, sure. If you know other toolkits then you already understand TkInter and can leave it until you actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not go for [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)? You apparently are already familiar with Qt, so it should be relatively easy to learn. In my opinion it looks better than Tkinter, and it sure is better documented.

Comment: I already use PyQt / PySide - question was about whether I should try Tkinter

Comment: Sorry, that was not completely obvious from your question.

Comment: Because PyQT comes with a big fat library. QT libs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used Qt with C++, but decided to have a go with Tkinter with Python. I had a bit of trouble installing the latest version of Tcl/Tk, but got there eventually. I did it all with the help of [this tkdocs.com tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/), which is great.

Comment: Tkinter comes with Python - idle uses it.

Comment: Yes, but not always the latest version.